# Fabricjs: Auto add border when export egText to PDF

Tags: pdf, canvas, fabricjs

I'm exporting a Fabricjs egText to PDF on Node server using PDFKit module.

It auto adds a border around my text when export to PDF.

On drawing canvas: [On drawing canvas img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKoV9.png)

On PDF: [On PDF img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITPZ.png)

As you see, it has a very light border around text.

And if I set the backgroundColor of text to rgb**a**(255, 255, 255, **0**), the border is disappear.

Do you know how to fix it or any sugguestion ?

When i add a white blackground rectangle under the text, the border is disappear on the part of text that on the rectangle, at the rest, the border still active.

The image here: [Two parts of text Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGNvK.png)

Comment: I think if you change the zoom level that line is moving or disappear, can you verify?

Comment: Do you mean zoom level of the canvas ? Do you have document link of zoom level ? My app has zoom in and zoom out feature but it export the same PDF at different zoom level

Comment: No zooming your output pdf in your pdf reader. do you see that line moving/changing or is fixed?

Comment: On pdf reader, the border is fixed.

Comment: When I add a white background rectangle under the text, the border disappears. The border only appear when the text is on canvas direct way (i mean no other object under the text.)

Comment: There are some added info at main question :D

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/tj93v1jg/), I didn't find any.

Comment: @Durga You 're using IText and jspdf (it 's client side), but I'm using egText and pdfKit - a Node module (server side). I can't reproduce the issue on jsfiddle

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi any help ?